# How to modally present a ViewController, and then the run a callback function / block after the ViewController has been dismissed, without Delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog

I was just knew that the completion block in the `self.presentViewController(childVc, animated: true, completion: {})` is called after the child view controller is finish getting animated to be *displayed* at the screen. I actually want to run a block of code that get displayed after the animation of child view controller is finished getting animated to be *dismissed*. How can I do that, preferrably avoiding using delegate to do that?

EDIT: I call this from the presented (child) view controller like this: `self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated (true) {}`, but the problem is the child view controller can be presented from arbitrary page, and after the child is dismissed, the parent (presenting) view controller has to do different things. If I implement the call back in the child, I can't do different thing with different parent that call it.

For example, if I call login form as modal in the news screen, after the login form dismissed, I want to display comment section afterwards. But if the login form modally displayed from product screen, I want to display the user's cart with the product in the cart afterwards. If this is impossible to be done without delegate, I still interested in the delegate solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a property to your `ChildVC` to store a callback closure and set this when you present the child view controller.  When the child view controller dismisses itself it can call the completion handler:

```
class ChildVC: UIViewController {        
    var completionHandler : ((childVC:ChildVC) -> Void)?

    func dismiss() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            self.completionHandler?(childVC:self)
        }
    }
}
```

You supply the completion handler when you present the ChildVC instance:

```
let completionHandler:(ChildVC)->Void = { childVC in
    print("completed for \(childVC)")
}
childVC.completionHandler=completionHandler
self.presentViewController(childVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Awesome, you even provide return value of which childVC was presented on the finishing block. Thanks!

Comment: in the self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true), self may be nil, and so may completionHandler. you need to make a reference to completionHandler in the upper closure (such as in the dismiss method level) and use that in the callback block

Answer (score 1):

Use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` API which takes a completion block.

```
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
        /* Do callback stuff here*/
    }
```

Comment: I call this from the presented (child) view controller like this: `self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated (true) {}`, but the problem is the child view controller can be presented from arbitrary page, and after the child is dismissed, the parent (presenting) view controller has to do different things. If I implement the call back in the child, I can't do different thing with different parent that call it.

Comment: For example, if I call login form as modal in the news screen, after the login form dismissed, I want to display comment section afterwards. But if the login form modally displayed from product screen, I want to display the user's cart with the product in the cart afterwards.

Comment: You need to supply the callback closure as a property to the childVC

Comment: @Paulw11 oooh, never thought of that! It's a great viable trade off between full blown delegate and the simplicity (and complexity) of not using delegate at all. Thanks! I think your answer is the most practical to implement for now. By the way, I think you need to make your comment as an answer. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can create a callback block in presented ViewController like that `@property(nonatomic,copy)void (^onDimissed)();` 
and after in presented view controller call 
`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        if (self.onDismissed) {
            self.onDismissed();
        }
    }];` 

So you can return any params in block 
And don't forget make this 

`SomeController *ctr = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 ctr.onDimissed = ^{
    //some your implementation
 };`

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! Is there any chance you could help me translate this into swift? Thanks!

Comment: Something like this  `class PresentedViewController: UIViewController {
    var onDismissed : (() -> Void)?
    func dismissPresented() -> Void {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
            if self.onDismissed != nil {
                self.onDismissed!()
            }
        }
    }
}

let presented = PresentedViewController();
presented.onDismissed = {
    () -> Void in //your implimentation}
    `

Answer (score -1):

If you using `self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated (true) {}` this return nil why means its not support all the OS, so simply use this below code,

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
   //Put your code
});
```

if you dismiss the `ViewController` you can call any function put your code in completion handler.

hope its helpful

Comment: No, I mean, I do not include the implementation inside the block because it's irrelevant to my question. I just say that the code inside the block is called after the child view animation presentation is done, which is not what I want. I want the block to be called after the child view animation dismiss is done. :)